# How do I add 3rd party javascript in Magento 2.4?

Tags: javascript, magento, installation

I was given some javascript from a 3rd party vendor and told to install it in Magento Admin Content/Configuration/HTML Head/Scripts and Style Sheets. Here is the code:

```
<script> (function(){ var s = document.createElement('script'); var h = document.querySelector('head') || document.body; s.src = 'https://3rdpartyvendor.com/apps/app/dist/js/app.js'; s.async = true; s.onload = function(){ acsbJS.init({ statementLink : '', footerHtml : '', hideMobile : false, hideTrigger : false, disableBgProcess : false, language : 'en', position : 'right', leadColor : '#146FF8', triggerColor : '#146FF8', triggerRadius : '50%', triggerPositionX : 'right', triggerPositionY : 'bottom', triggerIcon : 'people', triggerSize : 'bottom', triggerOffsetX : 20, triggerOffsetY : 20, mobile : { triggerSize : 'small', triggerPositionX : 'right', triggerPositionY : 'bottom', triggerOffsetX : 10, triggerOffsetY : 10, triggerRadius : '20' } }); }; h.appendChild(s); })(); </script>
```

When tried to install it in Content/Configuration/HTML Head/Scripts and Style Sheets it returns a 404 error after saving. I also tried pasting the code just before the  tag in app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml, but the widget that is supposed to appear on the frontend doesn't, and when I inspect the code in Chrome I don't see the code I pasted.

What would be the correct way to install this on a Magento 2.4 site?